# Spark unable to read kafka Topic and gives error " unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout 6000"

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to Execute the Example program given in Spark Directory on HDP cluster "*/spark2/examples/src/main/python/streaming/kafka_wordcount.py*" which tries to read kafka topic but gives Zookeeper server timeout error.

**Spark is installed on HDP Cluster and Kafka is running on HDF Cluster, both are running on different cluster and are in same VPC on AWS**

Command executed to run spark example on HDP cluster is  "bin/spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.0.jar examples/src/main/python/streaming/kafka_wordcount.py HDF-cluster-ip-address:2181 topic"

Error Image :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9tcT.jpg)

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2018-06-20 07:51:56
-------------------------------------------

18/06/20 07:51:56 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1529481116000 ms.0 from job set of time 1529481116000 ms
18/06/20 07:51:56 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.171 s for time 1529481116000 ms (execution: 0.145 s)
18/06/20 07:51:56 INFO PythonRDD: Removing RDD 94 from persistence list
18/06/20 07:51:56 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 94
18/06/20 07:51:56 INFO BlockRDD: Removing RDD 89 from persistence list
18/06/20 07:51:56 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 89
18/06/20 07:51:56 INFO KafkaInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[89] at createStream at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 of time 1529481116000 ms
18/06/20 07:51:56 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches: 1529481114000 ms
18/06/20 07:51:56 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 1529481114000 ms
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1529481117000 ms
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1529481117000 ms.0 from job set of time 1529481117000 ms
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 107 (call at /usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:2257)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 27 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141) with 1 output partitions
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 54 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 53)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 54 (PythonRDD[111] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48), which has no missing parents
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_27 stored as values in memory (estimated size 7.0 KB, free 366.0 MB)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_27_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.1 KB, free 366.0 MB)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_27_piece0 in memory on ip-10-29-3-74.ec2.internal:46231 (size: 4.1 KB, free: 366.2 MB)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 27 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1039
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 54 (PythonRDD[111] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 54.0 with 1 tasks
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 54.0 (TID 53, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7649 bytes)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 54.0 (TID 53)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 40, boot = -881, init = 921, finish = 0
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 41, boot = -881, init = 922, finish = 0
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 54.0 (TID 53). 1493 bytes result sent to driver
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 54.0 (TID 53) in 48 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 54.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 54 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141) finished in 0.055 s
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 27 finished: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141, took 0.058062 s
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ZooKeeper: Session: 0x0 closed
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 28 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141) with 3 output partitions
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 56 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 55)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 56 (PythonRDD[112] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48), which has no missing parents
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopping receiver with message: Error starting receiver 0: org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver onStop
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Deregistering receiver 0
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_28 stored as values in memory (estimated size 7.0 KB, free 365.9 MB)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_28_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.1 KB, free 365.9 MB)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_28_piece0 in memory on ip-10-29-3-74.ec2.internal:46231 (size: 4.1 KB, free: 366.2 MB)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 28 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1039
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 3 missing tasks from ResultStage 56 (PythonRDD[112] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(1, 2, 3))
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 56.0 with 3 tasks
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 54, localhost, executor driver, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7649 bytes)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 55, localhost, executor driver, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7649 bytes)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 56, localhost, executor driver, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7649 bytes)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 55)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 56)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 54)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
18/06/20 07:51:57 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Error starting receiver 0 - org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:880)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:171)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:126)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:143)
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:600)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:590)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopped receiver 0
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO BlockGenerator: Stopping BlockGenerator
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 40, boot = -947, init = 987, finish = 0
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 40, boot = -947, init = 987, finish = 0
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 41, boot = -944, init = 985, finish = 0
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 55). 1536 bytes result sent to driver
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 55) in 52 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/3)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 45, boot = -944, init = 989, finish = 0
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 40, boot = -32, init = 72, finish = 0
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 54). 1536 bytes result sent to driver
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 54) in 56 ms on localhost (executor driver) (2/3)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 40, boot = -33, init = 73, finish = 0
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 56). 1536 bytes result sent to driver
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 56) in 58 ms on localhost (executor driver) (3/3)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 56.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 56 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141) finished in 0.063 s
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 28 finished: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:141, took 0.065728 s
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2018-06-20 07:51:57
-------------------------------------------

18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1529481117000 ms.0 from job set of time 1529481117000 ms
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.169 s for time 1529481117000 ms (execution: 0.149 s)
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO PythonRDD: Removing RDD 102 from persistence list
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 102
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO BlockRDD: Removing RDD 97 from persistence list
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO KafkaInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[97] at createStream at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 of time 1529481117000 ms
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 97
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches: 1529481115000 ms
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 1529481115000 ms
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO RecurringTimer: Stopped timer for BlockGenerator after time 1529481117400
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO BlockGenerator: Waiting for block pushing thread to terminate
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO BlockGenerator: Pushing out the last 0 blocks
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO BlockGenerator: Stopped block pushing thread
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO BlockGenerator: Stopped BlockGenerator
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Waiting for receiver to be stopped
18/06/20 07:51:57 ERROR ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopped receiver with error: org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
18/06/20 07:51:57 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:880)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:171)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:126)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:143)
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:600)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:590)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/06/20 07:51:57 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:880)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:171)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:126)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:143)
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:600)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:590)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/06/20 07:51:57 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
18/06/20 07:51:57 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (start at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) failed in 13.256 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:880)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:171)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:126)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:143)
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:600)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:590)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
18/06/20 07:51:57 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Receiver has been stopped. Try to restart it.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:880)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:171)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:126)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:143)
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:600)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:590)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Caused by: org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:880)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:171)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:126)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:143)
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:600)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:590)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even on same VPC check for security groups of the two systems. If they have different security groups you probably need to allow inbound and outbound ports. Another way of verifying it is try to telnet and ping both systems from one another.

Comment: Thanks Arun for the help, I checked with telnet command, System were not able to ping each other. Now I have modified the security group and it's working.